# Opening new window on radiobutton selected with .net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, new-window

I have 2 radiobuttons as shown below:

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="ebrochType" Text="Select Type 1" TextAlign="Right" ID="rbtSelect1" OnCheckedChanged="sel1" AutoPostBack="true" />

<asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="ebrochType" Text="Select Type 2" TextAlign="Right" ID="rbtSelect2" OnCheckedChanged="sel2" AutoPostBack="true"  />
```

When one of these is selected, I need to open a page in a new window with no menubar etc...

Is this possible in the code behind?

I tried this but it did not work (it just refreshed the page/updatepanel):

```
Sub sel1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "select1", "window.open('http://www.google.co.uk','','')", True)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that from the code behind by adding an attribute to each radio button with the key "onclick" and value "javascript:window.open('your url',your parameters)".

Answer (score 0):

The 'modern' way to do this is with JQuery:

```
<div>
    <h3>Individual Radiobuttons</h3>
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rb1" Text="Apples" CssClass="rb" GroupName="individ" />
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rb2" Text="Oranges" CssClass="rb" GroupName="individ" />
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rb3" Text="Bananas" CssClass="rb" GroupName="individ" />
</div>


<div>
    <h3>RadiobuttonList</h3>

    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbList1" CssClass="rbList1" >
        <asp:ListItem Text="Cats" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Dogs" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Rabbits" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
```

Use an external Javascript file:
    `<script type='text/javascript' language='Javascript' src="/path/to/jscript/Tom.js'></script>`

1. In  your JQuery file you define an event handler for the onclick or onchange event.

   $(document).ready(function () {

   ```
   $(".rb").change(function () {
       window.open('http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&btnG=Search&q=' + $(this).text());
   });

   $(".rbList1").change(function () {
       //With RadiobuttonLists, the JQuery is a little more convoluted - a glance
       //at the markup will reveal why.
       window.open('http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&btnG=Search&q=' + $('.rbList1 :checked').next().text(), 'WindowFromRadiobuttonList', 'width=300,height=600');

   });
   ```

   });

HTH.